# Using Global Types With Lerna

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, typescript-typings, lerna

I have a `Lerna` project using Typescript with the following structure:

- packages/

  - commons/

    - types/

      - global.d.ts
  - partner/
  - user/

partner and user are both `Express.js` apps.

Inside commons I have a types folder with a `global.d.ts` file:

```
export {};

declare global {
    type UserInformation = {
        givenName: string;
        familyName: string;
        email: string;
        id: string;
        birthDate: string;
    }
}
```

I want to use this type across **all** packages (in commons, user and partner). 
What is the best way to do it?